# Format console timestamp

Tags: ros, rosout, timestamp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
We are facing non-human looking timestamp output in the console:

```
[ INFO] [1465210897.698024206]: Some log msg
```

while nicely readable in the log files:

```
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-06-06 12:35:22,972: Some other log msg
```

My rosconsole.conf is found and responds on log-level settings. Unfortunately any attempt to format the console timestamp format fails.

```
log4j.logger.ros=INFO
log4j.logger.ros.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

How to control this behaviour?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236155/format-console-timestamp/) by [langsware](https://answers.ros.org/users/27082/langsware/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2017-04-10**:
I would greatly appreciate something like this. I use robot upstart which dumps all the rosout lines into a single file. Its really hard to tell when a run took place since all of them get put into the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's a common request (see [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/174892/ros-log-file-change-of-time-stamping-format/) and [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/232590/how-to-configure-ros_info-to-print-a-human-readable-time/)). Doesn't look as if there's an solution, because nobody implemented this yet. If you are willing to contribute, a pull request would probably be appreciated.

P.S.: Personally, I find the "non-human-readable" time format more useful, since that's what's in the message headers and what you get in your code. But this is a matter of personal taste or use case and should be configurable.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2016-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2017-10-12**:
As long as I do not have to read the log files manually the "non-human-readable" format is ok for me as well. Where is this ROS time format specified and how could I convert it using a Python script to e.g. parse log files?